# span string mvc5 itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am trying to make selected words as bold using:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(person)) completedby = "<span style='font-weight: bold'> Assessment completed by: </span>" + person +  "\n";
        chunk = new Chunk(completedby + "\n" +
        "", (font5));
        paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        paragraph.Add(chunk);
        doc.Add(paragraph);
```

I get the following in the PDF file:

```
<span style='font-weight: bold'> Assessment completed by: </span>
```

Any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: ...what doesn't work exactly? Looks fine to me.

Comment: What is the question? What is wrong?

Comment: The text on the PDF file is <span style='font-weight: bold'> Assessment completed by: </span>.  I don't get bold font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using     HTMLWorker.ParseToList as below:

```
string completedby = @"<span style='font-size:10;'>";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(person)) completedby += "<br/><br/>" + "<b>"+"completed by: " +"</b>" + person + ", RN" + "<br/>";

                completedby += "</span>";
                var reader1 = new StringReader(completedby);
                var htmlarraylist1 = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(reader1, null);

                //add the collection to the document
                foreach (IElement t in htmlarraylist1)
                {
                    paragraph.Add(t);
                }
                doc.Add(paragraph);
```

Hope this could help someone.